# Firefox quantum progress bar in gnome

Tags: gnome, firefox

I`m using Ubuntu 18.04 (daily build) but this also happened in 17.10 . After updating firefox ( now in firefox Quantum ) the download progress bar is gone from the dock . Anyone knows how to get it working in firefox quantum ? Thanks

Comment: Unless someone posts a solution / configuration option you might consider filing a bug report.

Comment: You can't see it when you are downloading something?

Comment: Yes, I can't see when I'm downloading something ... I think this is because of the changes made in quantum .... I will try to file a bug report then. Thank you!

Comment: In the Windows FF57, the bar is displayed during the current session after a download. The position is different (between the url and search bars. I missed it at first). I can't say for Ubuntu though, because I had to leave that system at 52esr for extension compatibility.